# How to check the status of call command in dos batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos, batch-processing

I have a batch file name xyz.bat with these content

```
 @echo off
 echo  1.Cleaning all four project.
 call apacheant\bin\ant -buildfile clean-all.xml
```

> When the first call end it write on console  build succeed or build failed.
>   How do i verify that this call failed or passed moreover on this condition basis i want to decide the next call execution.

```
echo  1.Building all four project.
call apacheant\bin\ant -buildfile build-all.xml
@echo on
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo  1.Building all four project.
call apacheant\bin\ant -buildfile build-all.xml >logfile.txt
findstr "succeed" logfile.txt >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo Build failed) else (echo Build Succeeded)
```

Naturally, the `echo ...` could be replaced by 'set antstatus=SUCCEED` if required.

Don't try to use ERRORLEVEL to control the processing since MANY commands will change ERRORLEVEL to report their own status.

It may also be *possible* that `ANT` returns a status on termination. You could check with

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

after the `ant` step. If it returns an errorlevel, then you don't need to create and interpret the logfile.

The `IF ERRORLEVEL` syntax is

```
if errorlevel n Command_if_errorlevel_is_n_OR_GREATER_THAN_n
```

Comment: Certainly - that works, but IMHO, it's better to use the other construct. `%ERRORLEVEL%` is a `magic variable.` It does not appear on the `set` list, but if it is used then the environment is searched first for a value and **THEN** CMD gets the system value if the variable is NOT found in the environment. Using the `if errorlevel n` construct **ALWAYS** loads from the system AND works within a block (between the parentheses in an `IF` or `FOR`) so to me, it's better to habitually use `if errorlevel` so you completely avoid the potential traps. YMMV.